# Basic "jquery fancybox"

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have fancybox working as a [stand-alone page](http://dc-designz.com/3/fb-original) , but when I integrate the code back into the page I want to display [fancybox](http://dc-designz.com/3), I get nothing.

This is for the portfolio link on the page. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've had a quick look at your site and I get the following script error:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference
File: 3, Line: 7, Column: 1557

Comment: check u already loading any other js library. It may be conflict...

Answer (score 0):

You have quite many JavaScript errors on your page. Open developer tools to see them (hit F12 and open Console tab). JavaScript errors might prevent further execution of the code and therefore fancyBox might not work.